# How to make onion skin the same color as the sketch?

Tags: grease-pencil, 2d

I am doing an animation of a hand using Grease Pencil, and for the sketch, I have each finger and the thumb a different color.  How do I make the Onion Skin have the same colors as the sketch?

Comment: Hello, could you please provide a screenshot?

Comment: Does it answer your question ? https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/grease_pencil/properties/onion_skinning.html